# r - emmeans pairwise analysis for multilevel repeated measures ANCOVA

Tags: r, lm, emmeans

I'm building a repeated measures ANCOVA using a multi-level framework through the AOV package. I have one continuous response variable, two factor predictors, and 3 continuous covariates. My script for the model is below:

```
ModelDV <- aov(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2 + CV1 + CV2 + CV3 + Error(PartID/(IV1 + IV2 + IV1:IV2)), data)
```

A snippet of my data set shows how it is formatted:

```
PartID DV   IV1     IV2    CV1 CV2 CV3
1      56  CondA1  CondB1  Contunous values
2      45  CondA2  CondB2         -
3      32  CondA3  CondB1         -
4      21  CondA4  CondB2         -
1      10  CondA1  CondB1         -
2      19  CondA2  CondB2         -
3      35  CondA3  CondB1         -
4      45  CondA4  CondB2         -
```

My condiitons are embedded in the error term of the participant ID since this is a fully within repeated measures model.

I am attempting to conduct a pairwise analysis on these values. My output provides omnibus F-tests:

```
Error: PartID
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
CV1        1    348     348   0.442 0.5308  
CV2        1      9       9   0.011 0.9193  
CV3        1   3989    3989   5.063 0.0654 .
Residuals  6   4727     788                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: PartID:IV1
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)   
IV1        1   6222    6222   17.41 0.0024 **
Residuals  9   3217     357                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: PartID:IV2
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
IV2        2   6215  3107.7   16.18 9.51e-05 ***
Residuals 18   3457   192.1                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: PartID:IV1:IV2
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
IV1:IV2    2  575.2   287.6   1.764    0.2
Residuals 18 2934.4   163.0
```

When calculating emmeans via:

```
emm<-emmeans(Model, ~ IV1)
pairs(emm)
```

I get a sensible output.

However, when using this for the covariates:

```
emm<-emmeans(Model, ~ CV1)
pairs(emm)
```

I get the following output:

```
    contrast  estimate SE df z.ratio p.value
    (nothing)   nonEst NA NA NA      NA  
Results are averaged over the levels of: IV1, IV2
```

What am I doing wrong here that a pairwise comparison is not working for the covariate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is because you have made them covariates to control for them and not to consider them as part of the explanation for your model.  You of course could do pairwise comparisons for the covariates outside the model but not inside the model framework.  Longer [blogpost using these tools I wrote here](https://ibecav.netlify.app/post/ancova-example/)...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense... Just as a quick follow up question, if you could, how would I modify some of the covariates to act as explanatory variables to the model? Do I need to include them in the error term as well for that?

Comment: Typically if you start adding continuous variables (as predictors) to your modelling you have left traditional ANOVA/ANCOVA territory and entered GLM country.  At some level everything descends from GLM but the packages you'd use will start to vary.  lm itself will of course give you answers as well since aov rides over the top of lm in `r`

Comment: Awesome. And thank you for the blog link. The ANCOVA is still the right choice for this analysis, but now I also know which packages to pursue when attempting to adjust for explanatory variable weight. Thanks for your help!